# cascaded model (autoencoder + classifier) in keras

Tags: classification, keras, cascade, mode, autoencoder

I am building a cascaded model (an autoencoder model stacked with a classifier). The input to the autoencoder is a set of images and the output of the autoencoder will be fed in to a pretrained classifier.

```
    auto_input= Input(shape=(ch, height, width), name='x_autoen')

    auto_output = autoencoder(auto_input)
    auto_model = Model(input=auto_input, output=auto_output)

    class_output = classifier(auto_output)
    class_model = Model(input=auto_output, output=class_output)

    cascade_model = Model(input=auto_input, output=[auto_output, class_output])

    load_classifier_weights(cascade_model, classifier_weights_path)

    auto_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
    class_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy')
    cascade_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

but this returns the following error.

```
File "xxxx.py", line 33, in build_model
class_model = Model(input=auto_output, output=class_output)
File "/xxx/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1987, in __init__
str(layers_with_complete_input))
RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor x_autoen at layer "x_autoen". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

The classifier code:

```
def classifier(inputs):

    conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Dropout(0.2)(conv1)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)                                  
    #
    conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'', border_mode='same')(pool1)     
    conv2 = Dropout(0.2)(conv2)
    conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv2)       
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)                                       
    #
    conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool2)     
    conv3 = Dropout(0.2)(conv3)
    conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv3)      

    up1 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv3), conv2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)#192x24x24
    conv4 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up1)         
    conv4 = Dropout(0.2)(conv4)
    conv4 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv4)      
    #
    up2 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv4), conv1],, mode='concat', concat_axis=1)#96x48x48
    conv5 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up2)         
    conv5 = Dropout(0.2)(conv5)
    conv5 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv5)       
    #
    conv6 = Convolution2D(2, 1, 1, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv5)         
    conv6 = core.Reshape((2,patch_height*patch_width))(conv6)                          
    conv6 = core.Permute((2,1))(conv6)                                                  

    conv7 = core.Activation('softmax')(conv6)

    return conv7
```

Error after making corrections according to the Daniel's comment:

```
ValueError: The model expects 2 input arrays, but only received one array. Found: array with shape (1000, 1, 48, 48)
```

This was the code I used for training the cascaded network.

```
cascade_model .fit(imgs_train, imgs_train, nb_epoch=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[checkpointer])
enter code here
```

Comment: First, check your "classifier" model. Is it fully connected? I mean does the input pass through all layers until the output? It sounds like the model is interrupted by the message. (Posting the code to the "classifier" model may help).

Comment: Yes it is Daniel. I  have posted the code above

Comment: Your model needs two outputs as you defined it: `cascade_model .fit(imgs_train, [imgs_train,classes_train]`. If you don't want to give two outputs, then define it with only one output.

Comment: thank Daniel. It worked. How can I now confirm that the classifier in my cascaded model is in not training, instead using pretrained weights to generate the output. Only the autoencoder part should be training.

Comment: You should make `class_model.trainable = false` and all `class_model.layers[i].trainable = false` **before compiling**. And you should set the weights of each classifier layer somewhere.

Comment: thanks you for that Daniel

Comment: You can also make a copy of "layer.get_weights()" in some layer of the model to compare before and after training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the classifier seems to be connected.

Then I guess you probably have to give an independent input to `class_model`.

The system is probably having problems to start a model in the middle of the graph (the graph is the sequence of layers where the output of one layer goes as input of another).

Although everything seems connected, you're passing a tensor that is in the middle of the graph as input to a model. That's probably generating a problem.

When I do this, I do it this way:

```
class_input = Input((shapeforclassifierinput))    
class_output = classifier(class_input)
class_model = Model(input=class_input, output=class_output)
#If this gives an error, then your classifier is indeed not connected
#Then I'd suggest using the Concatenate(axis=1)([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv3), conv2])
```

Now, you join both models this way:

```
cascade_input = Input(shape=(ch, height, width))
auto_out = auto_model(cascade_input)  
class_out = class_model(auto_out)   
cascade_model = Model(input=cascade_input, output=[auto_out, class_out])
```

Comment: This way removes that error. However, when I try to train the cascaded network it gives an another error.  Please find the details of the error above.